# After "disable beta testing" in google play console, how to enable again?

Tags: android, testing, beta

My app is unloaded as a beta release, the tester can download and test the uploaded apk. After I pressed the "DISABLE BETA TESTING" button, and save it, the link for download apk become not available.

I don't know to enable the test again, because the "DISABLE BETA TESTING" button has not changed, it is always "DISABLE BETA TESTING", and I cannot found button like "ENABLE...", so, how can I enable the test to allow the download link available to tester again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable beta again by applying following steps:

1. Go to https://play.google.com/
2. Release Management
3. App releases
4. List item
5. Select Manage Beta
6. Go to Edit release (if beta is not disabled before)
7. Add apk from library then select the version of apk which you want to release under beta
8. Then press Add

I hope, answer will work for you.